# QTY "+" or "-" for Magento Product Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9.1, trying to add the Qty "+" and "-" Buttons on the Product Page. Buttons are displaying on the page but Qty increment and decriment not working perfectly.

here is my "*addtocart.phtml*"

```
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Buy'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>

    <div class="add-to-box">
    <label class="required-deatials"><?php echo 'Price:';?> </label><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
     <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>

            <div class="qty-wrapper">
            <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>

               <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo  $this->getMinimalQty($_product) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>"  class="input-text qty"/>

                <div class="nb-qty-wrap">
                <div id="up1" class="up">
                    <input type="button" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty ) &amp;&amp; qty &gt; 0 ) qty_el.value--;return false;" class="dn" />
                </div>
                <div id="dn1" class="dn"> 
                    <input type="button" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty )) qty_el.value++;return false;" class="up" />
                </div>  
                </div>
                </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and javascript is used for

```
    <script type ="text/javascript">
jQuery("div.qty-wrapper").append('<input type="button" id="up1" class="up" />').prepend('<input type="button" id="dn1" class="dn" />');
    jQuery(".up").click(function()
    {
        var currentVal = parseInt(jQuery(this).prev(".qty").val());

        if (!currentVal || currentVal=="" || currentVal == "NaN") currentVal = 0;

        jQuery(this).prev(".qty").val(currentVal + 1);
    });

    jQuery(".dn").click(function()
    {
        var currentVal = parseInt(jQuery(this).next(".qty").val());
        if (currentVal == "NaN") currentVal = 0;
        if (currentVal > 0)
        {
            jQuery(this).next(".qty").val(currentVal - 1);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

When I remove style class from theme i.e `<div class="nb-qty-wrap">` from the script its working fine. If I add style of the template it is not working.

Comment: what do you mean by "do not work perfectly"? they work but they add 3 instead of 1? Add your errors and state the desired behaviour

Comment: completely not working.

Comment: error message or code?

Comment: Your `.dn` is below `.qty` that's why `.next` is not working. Try `$(this).closest('.qty-wrapper').find('.qty').val()`

Comment: thank you for your solution

Comment: Remove "jQuery("div.qty-wrapper").append('<input type="button" id="up1" class="up" />').prepend('<input type="button" id="dn1" class="dn" />');"
You already have it in addtocart.phtml